# Matching Extension ID with local extension

Tags: google-chrome-app

We currently have our extension available in the store. However, we want to be able to set the same extension ID for local apps in development because we are working with managed policy. Is there a way to set the extension ID locally to match that of the extension that is in the store?
Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Just copy and use the `"key"` field in manifest.

Comment: This is the manifest that is installed from the store?

Comment: Yes, copy the field from webstore's manifest and use it in your dev version.

Comment: Thanks for your help